# How to prevent access PHP out of its directory in any way?

Tags: php, security, directory

I've tried to set `open_basedir` constant.

This way has a problem: I could bypass the limitation by calling `exec` PHP command
and I have the ability to call a terminal command with PHP.
I could block to use `exec` but I don't need to prevent terminal commands with PHP.

Only what I want to achieve is preventing access PHP out of some path I've set in `open_basedir` any possible way.

F.e
There is a path `/var/www/public_html/test`.
And `open_basedir="/var/www/public_html/test"`

I want to prevent PHP access out of the path in any possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't leave comment so i'll write here, what if you create specific user for run php

https://www.binarytides.com/php-fpm-separate-user-uid-linux/

and then set rights that he have access only for project folder

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101576/give-user-read-write-access-to-only-one-directory